# Angular 'PersonCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Hi I am trying to build my first Angular app with Typescript but I can not seem to bind a controller correctly.

This is my typescript code:

```
module App {
   var modules: string[] = ["App.Person"];
   angular.module('App', modules)
          .run([]);
} 

    module App.Person {
        angular.module('App.Person', []);
    }

module App.Person {
    angular.module("App.Person")
           .controller('PersonCtrl', PersonCtrl);

    interface IPersonScope extends ng.IScope {
        fullName: string;
    }

    interface IPersonCtrl {

    }

    class PersonCtrl implements IPersonCtrl{
        public $scope: IPersonScope;

        static $inject = ['$scope'];
        constructor($scope: IPersonScope) {
            this.$scope = $scope;
            this.init();            
        }
        init() : void  {
            this.$scope.fullName = 'Justin S.';
        } 
    }
}
```

This is my view code:

```
<article ng-app>
    <section ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="fullName"></p>
    </section>
</article>
```

**EDIT**
After updating my html like this:

```
   <article ng-app="App">
        <section ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
            <p ng-bind="fullName"></p>
        </section>
    </article>
```

I started geting the following error:

Uncaught Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined

All related javascript files are loaded on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the application name, the root module **App** or **App.Person** *(angular.module('App.Person'))* as a value into **`ng-app`**:

```
// this should be the root module name
<article ng-app="App">
// or App.Person
// <article ng-app="App.Person">
    <section ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <p ng-bind="fullName"></p>
    </section>
</article>
```

And also be sure, that the file with that definition is part of the page `<script>`